# How to put variables in :[range]r[ead] !{cmd}

Tags: vim

I am writing a vim plugin and I'd like to do something like this:

```
let variable = expand("%:p")
r! myScript path/to/dir variable
```

But, for some reason, it doesn't work. Is there any way to put VimScript variables in commands like `r!`?

Comment: Did you tried `: execute('r! '.myscript.path.variablename)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use execute command to include variable namesand registers with other commands.

```
    : execute('r! '.myscript.path.variablename)
```

The above command interprets the values of the variables and then executes the command.

Comment: Just keep in mind that `execute()` was added in Vim 7.4.2008 (actually, it was added in 7.4.1996 under the name `evalcmd()`, and renamed a few days later).  It's 99,32% safer to use `:exec` instead. ;)

Comment: @SatoKatsura: Don't let the parentheses confuse you. This is `:execute`, with the string arguments wrapped unnecessarily. For the new `execute()` function, you'd have to `:call` it (or `:echo` to see the returned output).